# How to bind a MongoDb _id to a property?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I want to connect my ASP.NET Core web app to MongoDB, but got an issue.

I have a little model of Car

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public ObjectId ID { get; set; }
public string Company { get; set; }
public string Model { get; set; }
public string Color { get; set; }

[Range(1, 100)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public double Price { get; set; }
```

I also have a method which adds first data to my database:
(in future I will add a method to the controller)

```
public async Task AddCar()
        {
            var mycar = new Car
            {
                Color = "red",
                Company = "my",
                Model = "x3",
                Price = 33
            };
            var collection = database.GetCollection<Car>("car");
            await collection.InsertOneAsync(mycar);
        }
```

Everything looks good, but when I run my program I get this data in DB 
[image: document in my db]

I want that the automatically generated `_id` property is matched with my `ID` property

What do I have to do to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried renaming your ID field _id (i.e. `public ObjectId _id`)?

Comment: if i rename my field into `_id` it will work.
but i would like to know how to bind my property with mongo `_id`

Comment: Try decorating it with the `[BsonId]` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `[BsonId]` decorator before the `[BsonRepresentation]` one to tell MongoDB you are referring to it's autogenerated document ID. What happens now is MongoDB adding ID to the document while creating it and also another ID (yours) that's represented as the `ObjectId` but since you aren't really generating the value for your `ObjectId`, it's a bunch of zeroes.